# Параллельный запуск функции по расписанию с разными параметрами

Tags: python

Как на python >3.8 реализовать параллельный запуск функций по расписанию, но с разными параметрами и чтобы работа скрипта не была привязана к версии операционой системы?

Ниже приведен пример конфиг файла. Скрип на python будет считывать конфиг, а далее в зависимости от заданной в конфиге периодичности должен запускать функцию fnc с заданным параметром в параллельном режиме. Для примера если пользователь задал в конфиге задал параметры 1m, 1h, 1d то в 00:00:00 каждого дня должно параллельно выполниться функции с параметрами fnc(timeframe = 1m), fnc(timeframe = 1h), fnc(timeframe = 1d). Как реализовать заданный функционал и максимально оптимально и правильно?

ini file

```
1m:fnc(timeframe = 1m)
5m:fnc(timeframe = 5m)
1h:fnc(timeframe = 1h)
4h:fnc(timeframe = 4h)
1d:fnc(timeframe = 1d)
1w:fnc(timeframe = 1w)
```

Comment: в 00:00:00 обязательно?

Comment: максимально близкое. я хочу считывать данные с бирж с разной периодичностью. делать пересчет и на основе расчетов принимать решение об открытии сделки

Comment: То есть нельзя задать время, в которое выполнится функция, она всегда выполняется в `00:00:00`? И значит в строке: `5m:fnc(timeframe = 5m)` используется только `5m` (чтобы передать его как параметр функции), а вся остальная строка игнорируется? Или все же функция должна выполняться каждый 5 мин и передавать как параметр 5m? Также если время запуска накладывается на другое - выполнить параллельно

Comment: @YuriyTigiev  запусти на celery

Comment: '''чтобы работа скрипта не была привязана к версии операционой системы''' на каких ос это должно работать ?

Comment: Как я понимаю 1m запускается каждую минуту , 5m каждые 5 минут и тд.. А не проще ли реализовать через time.sleep только привести значения в секунды (или конвертер в программу встроить). Запустить каждую функция в отдельном потоке и просматривать результаты работы.

Comment: OS: Windows, CentOS, Ubuntu, Mac

Comment: Я не просто хочу реализовать задумманное, но хочу понять как это делать правильно. Раньше делал несколько копий скрипта и запускал их кронтабом с разным расписанием. Это все не удобно и не правильно. Хочу научиться правильному решению и чтобы была поддержка asyncio еще

Comment: простите, но что за критерий правильно/ неправильно ?  работает?работает. значит всё правильно.

Comment: работает и правильно написанный код.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Можно, к примеру, опереться на монотонный таймер `asyncio` и `concurrent.futures.Executor` для распаралеливания.

```
import asyncio
import datetime
import time
import re
import concurrent.futures

tab = """
1m:fnc(timeframe = 1m)
5m:fnc(timeframe = 5m)
1h:fnc(timeframe = 1h)
4h:fnc(timeframe = 4h)
1d:fnc(timeframe = 1d)
1w:fnc(timeframe = 1w)
"""

TIMEZONE = 3*60
ms = {
  'm':1,
  'h':60,
  'd':24*60,
  'w':7*24*60
}


def fnc(**args):
    print(datetime.datetime.now(), args)


def dispatcher(loop, pool, crontab):
    time_seconds = time.time()
    delay_seconds = (time_seconds//60+1) * 60 - time_seconds
    loop.call_later(delay_seconds, dispatcher, loop, pool, crontab)
    minute = time_seconds // 60 + TIMEZONE
    for interval, callback, name, value in crontab:
        if minute % interval == 0:
            pool.submit(callback, **{name: value})


def get_crontab():
    reg = re.compile("([0-9][mhdw]*):([a-z]*)\(([a-z][a-z0-9]*).*([0-9][mhdw]*)\)", re.M)
    crontab = [list(line) for line in reg.findall(tab)]
        
    for line in crontab:
        v,m = re.match(r'([0-9]*)([mhdw])', line[0]).groups()
        v = int(v)
        m = ms[m]
        line[0] = v * m
        line[1] = globals()[line[1]]
    return crontab


pool = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5)
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
dispatcher(loop, pool, get_crontab())
loop.run_forever()
```

На моем компютере задержка от часов получилась в пределах 0,003-0,060 секунды

get_crontab - переводит формат из примера текста в список: интервал, функция, аргумент, значение.

pool - это 5 потоков, которые почти одновременно запустят функции. Замените на `ProcessPoolExecutor` если нужно разгрузиться по всем ядрам.

loop - это асинхронный цикл, который в этом случае получает сигналы монотонного таймера от ядра системы.

dispatcher - в первую очередь запланирует себя к выполнению в 00 секунд следующей минуты. А потом выполнит функции из списка, которые должны выполнится в текущей минуте.

pool.submit - паралельно запускает функцию в одном из потоков пула.

### Конкурентный вариант (не паралельно, но асинхронно)

```
import asyncio
import datetime
import time
import re
import concurrent.futures
import inspect
import functools

tab = """
1m:fnc(timeframe = 1m)
5m:fnc(timeframe = 5m)
1h:fnc(timeframe = 1h)
4h:fnc(timeframe = 4h)
1d:fnc(timeframe = 1d)
1w:fnc(timeframe = 1w)
"""

TIMEZONE = 3*60
ms = {
  'm':1,
  'h':60,
  'd':24*60,
  'w':7*24*60
}


async def fnc(**args):
    print(datetime.datetime.now(), args)


def dispatcher(loop, crontab):
    time_seconds = time.time()
    delay_seconds = (time_seconds//60+1) * 60 - time_seconds
    loop.call_later(delay_seconds, dispatcher, loop, crontab)
    minute = time_seconds // 60 + TIMEZONE
    if time_seconds % 60 > 5:
        return 
    for interval, callback, name, value in crontab:
        if minute % interval == 0:
            if inspect.iscoroutinefunction(callback):
                loop.create_task(callback(**{name: value}))
            elif inspect.isfunction(callback):
                loop.call_soon(functools.partial(callback, **{name: value}))


def get_crontab():
    reg = re.compile("([0-9][mhdw]*):([a-z]*)\(([a-z][a-z0-9]*).*([0-9][mhdw]*)\)", re.M)
    crontab = [list(m) for m in reg.findall(tab)]
        
    for line in crontab:
        v,m = re.match(r'([0-9]*)([mhdw])', line[0]).groups()
        v = int(v)
        m = ms[m]
        line[0] = v * m
        line[1] = globals()[line[1]]
    return crontab


async def main():
    dispatcher(loop, get_crontab())

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: Как добиться того, чтобы при запуске скрипта функции не запускались, если они время старта не находится в пределах  00 - 05 секунд? Для примера этого вызова функции не должно было быть - 2021-01-05 11:22:13.654277 {'timeframe': '1m'}.  И как добавить loop.run_forever() в def async main() для asyncio.run(main()) ?

Comment: поставь условие перед for для предела в 5 секунд `if time_seconds % 60 < 5: for...`

Comment: асинк маин... тут же параллельное выполнение. вся асинхронность делается через таски в колбэках. Если нужен конкурентный запуск - надо бы убрать пул. что-то ещё будет выполнятся в main() ?

Comment: добавил асинхронный вариант

Answer (score 4):

### Вариант через `time.sleep` и `multiprocessing`

```
import multiprocessing
import datetime
import time
import re


tab = """
1m:fnc(timeframe = 1m)
5m:fnc(timeframe = 5m)
1h:fnc(timeframe = 1h)
4h:fnc(timeframe = 4h)
1d:fnc(timeframe = 1d)
1w:fnc(timeframe = 1w)
"""

TIMEZONE = 3*60
ms = {
  'm':1,
  'h':60,
  'd':24*60,
  'w':7*24*60
}


def fnc(**args):
    print(datetime.datetime.now(), args)


def dispatcher(pool, crontab, time_seconds):
    minute = time_seconds // 60 + TIMEZONE
    for interval, callback, name, value in crontab:
        if minute % interval == 0:
            pool.apply_async(callback, kwds={name: value})


def get_crontab():
    reg = re.compile("([0-9][mhdw]*):([a-z]*)\(([a-z][a-z0-9]*).*([0-9][mhdw]*)\)", re.M)
    crontab = [list(m) for m in reg.findall(tab)]
        
    for line in crontab:
        v,m = re.match(r'([0-9]*)([mhdw])', line[0]).groups()
        v = int(v)
        m = ms[m]
        line[0] = v * m
        line[1] = globals()[line[1]]
    return crontab

pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
crontab =  get_crontab()


while True:
    time_seconds = time.time()
    dispatcher(pool, crontab, time_seconds)
    delay_seconds = (time_seconds//60+1) * 60 - time.time()
    time.sleep(delay_seconds)


pool.terminate()
pool.join()
```

Comment: Какой из двух вариантов лучше ? Как выбрать? У меня сами асинхронные функции внутри себя будут вызывать другие ассинхронные функции для закачки данных. В случае сбоя или ошибки внутри вызванной в dispatcher функции, конкретная функция должна перестать работать, а другие должны продолжить свое выполнение

Comment: функция отправленная в пул уже не вызовет исключения на основном цикле.

Comment: вариант с asyncio  можно легко переделать с паралельного на конкурентный заменив пул на loop.create_task